# Unhandled exception in marshal.cxx under VS2013

Tags: c++, exception, visual-studio-2013

Debugging my C++ app I'm getting an occasion unhandled exception in marshal.cxx with the following stack trace;

> ole32.dll!CStdMarshal::Disconnect(unsigned long dwType)  Line 3420  C++
>       ole32.dll!CStdMarshal::DisconnectAndRelease(unsigned long dwType)  Line 3161 + 0x11 bytes   C++
>       ole32.dll!COIDTable::ThreadCleanup()  + 0x31bed bytes   C++
>       ole32.dll!FinishShutdown()  Line 1035   C++
>       ole32.dll!ApartmentUninitialize(int fHostThread)  Line 1291 C++
>       ole32.dll!wCoUninitialize(COleTls & Tls, int fHostThread)  Line 2766 + 0x7 bytes    C++
>       ole32.dll!CoUninitialize()  Line 2632   C++
>       networkitemfactory.dll!FDBackgroundThreadHandler()  + 0x25 bytes
>       shlwapi.dll!WrapperThreadProc()  + 0x116 bytes
>       kernel32.dll!BaseThreadInitThunk()  + 0xd bytes 
>       ntdll.dll!RtlUserThreadStart()  + 0x21 bytes

Slightly perplexed, as he main application thread is sitting in the message pump, and all my other threads are sleeping and nowhere near any of my own code.  Following on from this the debugger refuses to run my program at all until I exit and re-run visual studio.

Is there any way to figure out whether this is a problem in my code, or a problem in VS2013 or one of the plug-ins I'm using (Visual Assist and Visual Commander)?

Comment: Tends to be associated with a mis-behaving shell extension.  Perhaps you use a shell dialog in your app, GetOpenFileName() or IFileDialog.  Beyond debugger load notifications for those DLLs and the debugger's Modules window, you can use SysInternals' AutoRuns to disable them.

Comment: Have you tried running under Application Verifier and letting it monitor the app?

Comment: Hans, I think you may have hit the nail on the head.  I Use the MFC CFileDialog in my application which is often very slow and tends to throw other exceptions under the debugger.  I also have a number of explorere extensions installed such as TortoiseSVN.  Thanks for the heads up about SysInternals Autoruns, as I hadn't been aware of this app.  I'll try it out and see how I get on.

Comment: Having this issue too. Does anyone find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

The similar problem described here: 
http://mfctips.com/2012/10/29/cfiledialogdomodal-causes-access-violation/ 
The hotfix is here:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2718841/en-us 
Hope it helps.

Comment: Both links are dead