# "Unhandled exception at 0x000007FEFD5D7C8A (ole32.dll) in myprogram.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF"

Tags: c++, qfile

I'm trying to use QfileDialog (as a static fct) for the user to select and read a ".txt" file, as follow:

```
void VisOCMConfig::readNmbTiles()
{
    QString  m_findFile;
    m_findFile = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(0, tr("Open TextFile"),
                                              QDir::homePath(), tr("Text files (*.txt)"));

    QFile myfile(m_findFile);
    if (!myfile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text))
        return;
    else 
        while (!myfile.atEnd()) 
        {
            m_scanPos = myfile.readLine();
            m_nmbofLines++;
        }

    myfile.close();
    qDebug() << "Scan Positions: (" << m_scanPos.size() << "): " << m_scanPos;
    m_nmbofScan->setText(QString("#Tiles: %1").arg(m_nmbofLines));
}
```

Where m_scanPos is a QByteArray initialized in VisOCMConfig.h.

When I run the programm, It works correctly until a break occurs suddenly with the following message:

> Unhandled exception at 0x000007FEFD5D7C8A (ole32.dll) in
>   VisOCMConfig.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location
>   0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF

I read on other questions that it might be due to the use of null pointer but i'm still lost about it. Can you identify my mistake?

Comment: What were your observation from your debugging?

Comment: _i'm a newbie on c++ and on this forum._ Well, there's your first mistake - SO is **not** a forum. _I read on other questions that it might be **due to the use of null pointer** but i'm still lost about it._ Well, looking at the error message, it is more like _due to dereferencing pointer that has its value set to -1_.

Comment: Where does the access violation occur?  You need to step through in a debugger.

Comment: Hmm.  I changed the tag to QFile rather than QFileDialog, but if the problem is the call to QFileDialog, that may have been a mistake.  **Where does the access violation occur**.  Set a break point on the first line of the function and step through.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Weird thing is, when I make a step through all the function, there is no break. The break occurs afterwards... But I'm pretty sure that this function is the source of the problem, specifically the QFileDialog line, because when I comment it, there is no problem anymore...

Comment: It looks like a dynamic library that is need didn't load. Can you check all dependencies are present and reachable from the loader?

Comment: @MartinBonner Not sure mentioning works in the answer I wrote, so what to say also here that tag of this question should be changed back to QFileDialog. The relation is clear.

Answer (score 1):

I've been having the same issue. Try using "DontUseNativeDialog" as a flag. I believe this solves the crash, but then you are left with a non-native dialog.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. Solution is also to use a non-native QFileDialog.
Actually it only appears in Debug mode. In Release mode evething is fine.

The same code is working under QT4.8. Somehow it is not when using QT5.6.

Comment: I can confirm that I have a very similar problem. I could solve it similarly (by not using the static call to QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(...)). Nevertheless I wonder if this is a bug that is known to the Qt developers or if it needs to be reported. Does anybody know a reference to an official Qt bug?

Answer (score 0):

Those who downvoted this question (I upvoted it) are more than welcome to downvote also this my answer.

I have the same problem with Qt 5.2.1 - same exception in ole32.dll after using QFileDialog::getOpenFileName() - not immediately but after 10 - 60 seconds. It happens if I continue with application AND ALSO if do nothing after opening file, just wait some time.
Using "DontUseNativeDialog" as suggested by @aeson and @guest avoids this problem.
I hope this information can help others.

@MartinBonner I think the tag should be changed back to QFileDialog because the problem is clearly related to it

Answer (score -1):

I had the same error - my application crashed in debug mode.

If you examine the call stack when this issue occurs, you notice that the issue is related to the NetworkItemFactory.dll component.

A similar problem is described here: [Unhandled exception in marshal.cxx under VS2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27489516/unhandled-exception-in-marshal-cxx-under-vs2013?rq=1)

Microsoft fixed this, so the solution is to apply Microsoft's hotfix [Windows6.1-KB2718841](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2718841/0xc0000005-error-message-and-windows-explorer-stops-responding-on-a-co)